# Invalid target board - jetson-tx2-devkit

Tags: backup, nvidia-jetson

I want to create an image from nvidia jetson tx2 using flash.sh file, I could manage run it, but throw an error.

**I set board on Recovery Mode and execute:**

```
sudo /bin/bash ./flash.sh -r -k APP -G nvidia.img jetson-tx2 mmcblk0p1

   Error: Invalid target board - jetson-tx2-devkit.
```

I'm using a jetson tx2 p3310-1000, so the name is correct, no matter I tried with jetson-tx2 and nothing.

*Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, Jetpack 4.5.1*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be sure that you are using the correct flash file with your Jetpack, for the case of version 4.5.1 you could use this code (for other version, please check L4T Driver Package (BSP) in https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra)

```
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/l4t/r32_release_v5.1/r32_release_v5.1/t186/tegra186_linux_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2
tar -xjvf tegra186_linux_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2 
rm tegra186_linux_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2 
cd Linux_for_Tegra/rootfs
sudo wget https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/l4t/r32_release_v5.1/r32_release_v5.1/t186/tegra_linux_sample-root-filesystem_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2
sudo tar -xjvf tegra_linux_sample-root-filesystem_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2
sudo rm tegra_linux_sample-root-filesystem_r32.5.1_aarch64.tbz2 && cd ..
sudo ./apply_binaries.sh
sudo /bin/bash ./flash.sh -r -k APP -G nvidia.img jetson-tx2-devkit mmcblk0p1
```

[nothing else to edit]